# How to delete a text area with the click of a button in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a button that will delete the text area above it in AngularJS. I am creating a note taking program and so far I have been able to post the notes but I cannot delete the notes. Here is what the code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">       </script>
 <body>
 <style>
  #par1{
    text-align: left;
   }
  .wideInput{
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
   }

  .stuff{
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }


 </style>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <p id="par1">Notes <br>
 <textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="name"></textarea>
 <br>

 <button type="button" ng-click="addNote()" ng-model="button">Submit</button>
 <button type="button" ng-model="delete">Delete</button>

    <div class="stuff" ng-repeat="note in notes">
        <textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="note" ng-    repeat="writing in writings"></textarea><br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addNote()" ng-model="button">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="deleteNode(this)" ng- model="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
<!--        

    <li class="stuff">
        <button type="button" ng-click="addNote()">Submit</button>
    </li>
    //-->






</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
       $scope.notes=[]
       $scope.buttons=[]
       $scope.writings=[{}]
       $scope.addNote=function(){
          $scope.notes.push({});
       }
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to post a picture yet. Any suggestions as to how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p id="par1">Notes <br>
 <textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="name"></textarea>
 <br>

<button type="button" ng-click="addNote()" ng-model="button">Submit</button>
<button type="button" ng-model="delete">Delete</button>

    <div class="stuff" ng-repeat="note in notes"> <!-- As long as you are not using orderBy -->
        <textarea class="wideInput" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="note" ng-    repeat="writing in writings"></textarea><br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addNote()" ng-model="button">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="deleteNote($index)" ng- model="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
<!--        

    <li class="stuff">
        <button type="button" ng-click="addNote()">Submit</button>
    </li>
    //-->






</div>

    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.notes=[]
    $scope.buttons=[]
   $scope.writings=[{}]

$scope.deleteNote = function(index){
   $scope.notes.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.addNote=function(){
$scope.notes.push({
})

}

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks I really appreciate it. Why does the $index work as a parameter for the deleteNode() method in ng-click? How does it know to select the index of the text area?

Comment: ng-repeat gives you some helper values which can be useful in web development ( take a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat ). It knows the $index of the item because you are looping through array so in that case you know which item at what position are going to be bound to DOM. We are simply passing this value to function. $index value will be correct as long as you are not using orderBy filter.

Comment: But if I'm at the fifth element in the array and I want to delete the second. Wouldn't $index=4? How would it know to go back to the second element if I hit the delete button for the second text area?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but when you delete element in array then ng-repeat will rerender collection because of $digest process - which means that indexes will be refreshed according to item position in array. Did I've answered your question?

Comment: What I was asking is that say if I hit the "Submit" button (in this example) five times and I wanted to delete the second box. How would $index know to grab the second value based on me clicking the second "Delete" button?

Comment: Right so the answer is like my above, it will know to grab the second value because it applies $index ( so position of item in array ) per item, and if you click on second item - still it is at index = 1 in array so we are just passing that value to the function - even if you add more items.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. Would you happen to know how to get rid of the default [Object object] in the text areas?

Comment: Yes, note is an object right? So bind your text area to note.textAreaValue ( or any other field that you would like to get updated on change ). Setting ng-model to note.textAreaValue should help

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it